# Div de 100% width se superpone a un 'span' flotando a la izquierda

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente código HTML:

```
<div class="tags-notice">
      <span class="item-tags"></span>
      <div class="content-etiquetas"></div>
</div>
```

Y quiero que el `div.content-etiquetas` quede enfrente del `span` y ocupe hasta el `100%` de su contenedor, pero si le digo al `div` que haga el `100%` se pone encima del `span`.

#### CSS:

```
.item-tags{
    width: 35px;
    height: 32px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-mask-size: cover;
    background-color: rgb(189,189,189);
    -webkit-mask: url(../images/botones/etiquetas.svg)!important;
    mask: url(../images/botones/etiquetas.svg) !important;
}

.content-etiquetas{
   width: 100%;
    min-height: 32px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

¿Como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: ¿Cómo se tendrían que mostrar? ¿Uno al lado del otro?

Comment: si , el span y enfrente el div siempre , en todos los tamaños, y el div debe ocupar el 100% ((( desde el span hasta el borde del contenedor))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, pero este comportamiento es completamente normal.

1. Si está dando `width: 100%;` a un `child`, el elemento respetará el `width` de lo elemento *parent*. Y debido a eso que el elemento está ocupando el 100% de los padres.
2. Cuando usted da `float: left;` al primer niño, después tienes que limpiar el flotador usando `clear:left;` ou `clear:both;` em um novo elemento, o agregar el flotador a los elementos siguientes también, si no usted tendrá ese comportamiento de los elementos estén uno encima del otro porque el `clear` no ocurrió ni los elementos siguientes tienen flotador

Ejemplo visual de la descripción anterior (`2`):

```
<div class="elemento float-left"></div>
<div class="clear-float"></div>
<div class="elemento-sin-float"></div>
```

```
.float-left {float:left;}
.clear-float {clear:both;}
```

O flotar cada elemento, y al final limpiar `float`:

```
<div class="float-left"></div>
<div class="float-right"></div>
<div class="clear-float"></div>
```

```
.float-left {float:left;}
.float-right {float:right;}
.clear-float {clear:both;}
```

3. En este caso, para poner las dos `divs` lado a lado, tendremos que hacer algunos cálculos... Que en este caso queremos poner una pequeña `div` primero, y una más grande que ocupa la mayor parte del espacio. Digamos que la `div` más grande tendrá 90% del espacio. Si quitarmos `90%` de `100%`, `10%` será el resto. Así la nuestra otra `div` será `width: 10%;` que es el resto.

### Aquí hay un ejemplo más visual

```css
.item-tags{
    width: 10%;
    height: 32px;
    float: left;
    background-color: rgb(89, 89, 89);
}

.content-etiquetas{
    width: 90%;
    min-height: 32px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags-notice">
      <span class="item-tags"></span>
      <div class="content-etiquetas"></div>
</div>
```

Tenga en cuenta que se utilizó `box-sizing: border-box;` con el fin de lidiar con lo "`1px`" de espacio extra de la `border`. Al contrario no tería el mismo efecto. Leer más sobre esto en [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) y tanbien en [Treehouse](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/box-sizing-secret-simple-css-layouts)

---

## (edición) Otra solución alternativa mejor y más adecuada para su problema

```css
.tags-notice {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.tn-item {display: table-cell;}

.item-tags{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: rgb(89, 89, 89);
}
.content-etiquetas{
    min-height: 32px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags-notice">
      <span class="tn-item item-tags"></span>
      <div class="tn-item content-etiquetas"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, sin embargo creo que mi problema no puede ser resuelto porque tu distribuyes el 100% en 10% y luego 90% pero mi span no debe ser mayor a 32 pixeles, Muchas gracias igualmente por tu respuesta aprendi muchas cosas

Comment: Listo @AndressBlend , he añadido una nueva versión para esta solución

Comment: Muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error en tu codigo

```
.item-tags{
    width: 35px;
    height: 32px;
    display: block; <-- Pon esto aqui
    float: left; <-- QUITA EL FLOAT, PARA QUE NO SE PONGA A LA DERECHA
    -webkit-mask-size: cover;
    background-color: rgb(189,189,189);
    -webkit-mask: url(../images/botones/etiquetas.svg)!important;
    mask: url(../images/botones/etiquetas.svg) !important;
}

.content-etiquetas { <--- Cambia el punto de lugar al inicio
   width: 100%;
    min-height: 32px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: block; <--- Pon esto aqui
}
```

Prueba a ver si te funciona

Comment: perdòn fue al copiar que se me fue mal el punto

Comment: agrega el display a ambos

Comment: ya, pero aun no , el div sigue estando encima del span cuando le pongo 100% de width

Comment: Amigo, es por el float en el .item-tags, quitalo y pruebalo.

Answer (score 0):

Agregale z-index a tu clase.

```
content-etiquetas.{
   width: 100%;
    min-height: 32px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    z-index: 1000
}
```

Comment: el problema es que se sigue viendo encima de la etiqueta y quiero que se vea al lado derecho de esta

Comment: z-index Sólo funciona si tienes un position declarado.

Comment: min-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    min-height: 32px;
    z-index: 90999;

y con absolute se sale del contenedor